# How do I diagnose overparameterization in Bayesian parameter estimation?

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, random-variable, random-effects-model, convergence

I am fitting a linear mixed effects model (with random slopes and intercepts, for subjects and items) containing several fixed effects and their interactions, using Bayesian parameter estimation. (In particular I am using the "brms" package in R.)

I am using non-informative priors, and essentially using this approach to be able to use MCMC sampling to estimate my model.

I seem to notice that this approach can handle more fixed and random effects, while still converging, than the "lme4" package.

I used to use non-convergence, and perfectly correlated random intercepts, as red flag for overparameterization. However, using this Bayesian approach, my models converge well (diagnosed using Rhat).

My question is: assuming my models converge, is there something else I should be checking to guard against overparameterization?